# Is it possible to run multiple instances of Python to process items from a csv?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I want to process a csv of urls, probably 3000 rows. The program I'm running is pretty slow about 10 seconds per url so I was wondering if it is possible to write a program that will run the original program multiple times concurrently to save time. I saw parallel processing in my search, but I think that term applies to multiple cpu's which is not my situation.

My idea is to somehow read the top row and delete it and record the next row with a url kind of like a stack pointer.

Comment: Yes, It's called multithreading. Read more about the `threading` library, it's best suited for your use case.

Comment: @SalmanFarsi It's more multiprocessing than multithreading. For parallel work, mutlithreading is useless.

Comment: @Itération122442 That's not categorically true, nor relevant in this case. The bottleneck in this situation is some few thousands of HTTP network requests, so concurrent threading is more than sufficient for "parallel behavior"

Comment: Yes, but the question contains `concurrently` as a criteria.

Comment: what is the difference between multi threading and multi processing?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example of how to concurrently process a list of data using threads:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def process_row(row):
    time.sleep(1)  # pretend to do 1 sec of work
    return row[0]


csv_rows = [['foo'], ['bar'], ['baz']]


with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
    results = pool.map(process_row, csv_rows)

print(list(results))  # only takes 1 second instead of three
```

Comment: This is multithreading. In python, threads are not executed in parralel.

Comment: That's not the critical bottleneck to address in this situation and therefore an unimportant concern

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
import csv, time, sys, concurrent.futures

#Process the url
def process_url(url):

    # Note: If you want to update some file in this function or do some operation synchronously use the threading.Lock() 
    # functionality to ensure thread safety
    print(url)

if __name__=="__main__":
    input_file = sys.argv[1]
    with open(input_file,"r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        url_list = [row[1] for row in reader]      

    t = time.time()
    NUM_WORKERS = 4 

    #Use MultiThread - Using concurrent.futures to abstract out the low level thread manipulations
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(NUM_WORKERS) as executor:
        executor.map(process_url, url_list)  

    print(time.time()-t)
```

Just reiterating, if you're doing some synchronous operation in the `process_url` function, make sure to use `threading.Lock()`. Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) for more information.

Comment: This is multithreading. In python, threads are not executed in parralel.

Comment: Yes, but in this use case multithreading is faster. Multiprocessing is an overkill for this task since it doesn't require CPU intensive operations. You can time the code and see the difference.